# JPA Mapping issue one table with multiple tables

Tags: jpa

I have a table for managing approval and I don't want add more additional columns as a reference to it

**Approval.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public  class Approval {
  @Id
  private int id;
  @Column
  private int doc_key; 
  @Column
  private int stage; 
  @Column
  private int status; 
  //getter and setter
}
```

and I have tow type of documents RFQ and Contract which need approval

**RFQ.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public  class RFQ {
  @Id
  private int id;

  @Column
  private int status; 

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dockey" , fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Approval> approvallist; 

}
```

**Contract.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public  class Contract {
     @Id
      private int id;

     @Column
      private int status; 

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dockey" , fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private List<Approval> approvallist; 


}
```

as you see I am using this association mapping :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dockey" , fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

but it is not working unless I have one of document classes RFQ or Contract
what if I want to add another document like Porposal foe example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the database point of view, your desired situation can be modeled using multiple possibilities:

1. Create a (abstract) base class `Document` that contains the one to many relationship and let both specific document types inherit from it - so you end up with a document table that gets referenced by the `doc_key` column.
2. Map the relationship between specific document types and approvals using dedicated tables so each specific document type contains a one to many relationship to a e.g. `RFQApproval` that contains the `ID` of the `RFQ` and the `ID` of the `Approval` and you remove the `doc_key` from the `Approval`.

My personal preference is 1 because this reflects the thinking of "each approval links to a document" and "RFQ and Contracts are documents" in terms of object oriented thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Use JoinColumn, not mappedBy

```
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

     @JóinColumn(name="dockey", referenceColumnName="doc_key")
       private List<Approval> approvallist;
```

Do the same for other entity. I asume thet aproval table has a doc_key column and  RFQ and contract  has a dockey column.

Answer (score 0):

SkillSet is like an Approval class.

```
public class Project {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    @ColumnPosition(position = 1)
    private Integer projectId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable( 
            name = "MAP_PROJECT_SKILL_SET", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SKILL_SET_ID"), 
            schema = Constants.DB_SCHEMA_NAME
            ) 
    private List<SkillSet> skillSet= new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @ColumnPosition(position = 1)
    private Integer projectId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable( 
            name = "MAP_EMPLOYEE_SKILL_SET", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SKILL_SET_ID"), 
            schema = Constants.DB_SCHEMA_NAME
            ) 
    private List<SkillSet> skillSet = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class SkillSet {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SKILL_SET_ID")
    @ColumnPosition(position = 1)
    private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: I like it I will try to do it